# What does 持てる mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

「持てる力をふりしぼる。」

Does it mean "to be possesed" (just from 持てる) or "to can have" (potential, from 持つ)? The context doesn't help, they're both fine to me.

Comment: Please, even if the context doesn't help you, it will definitely help other people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This 持てる is a [set phrase from classical Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42724/5010) which corresponds to 持っている in modern Japanese ("perfective form" of 持つ, used attributively, i.e., "which one has gained" or "who has gained [things]"). There is no potential sense.

> 持てる力をふりしぼる
> = 持っている力をふりしぼる
>
> to use up all one's strength

Grammatically, it's the realis form (已然形) of 持つ followed by the attributive form (連体形) of [り](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009007.htm), an auxiliary in classical Japanese.

Practically speaking, you can forget the classical grammar and just remember this as a fixed (or ["fossil"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_word)) rentaishi that appears almost exclusively in the following patterns:

- 持てる力, 持てる知識, 持てる能力, 持てる財産, ...
  (all) one's ～; all ～ one has
- 持てる者, 持てる人, 持てる貴族, ...
  haves (as in "haves and have-nots"); wealthy/gifted ～

These correspond to the fourth and fifth definitions [here](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B).

See also: [The meaning of モテる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/91118/5010)

Comment: モテモテ is also derived from 持てる?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer モテモテ is from another もてる described in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/91121/5010).

Comment: @rjh No, that's just the potential form of 持つ. It's nothing more than "can have".